# How to return a dictionary | Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a .txt file with the following lines in it:

```
23;Pablo;SanJose
45;Rose;Makati
```

I have this program:

```
file = open("C:/Users/renato/Desktop/HTML Files/myfile2.txt")

def query(id):
    for line in file:
        table = {}
        (table["ID"],table["name"],table["city"]) = line.split(";")
        if id == int(table["ID"]):
             file.close()
             return table
        else:
             file.close()
             return {}

id = int(input("Enter the ID of the user: "))
table2 = query(id)
print("ID: "+table2["ID"])
print("Name: "+table2["name"])
print("City: "+table2["city"])
```

So what's happening (according to me) is:

File is opened
A hash called `table` is created and each line of the file is split into 3 keys/values.
If the `id` entered by the user matches the value of the key `ID`, then close the file
and return the whole hash.

Then, I'm assigning `table2` the values on the `table` hash and I'm trying to print the values in it.

When I run this, I get the following:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/renato/Desktop/HTML Files/Python/hash2.py", line 17, in <module>
    print("ID: "+table2["ID"])
    KeyError: 'ID'
```

It seems like it's not recognizing the key `ID` on the `table2` var. I also tried declaring `table2` as a hash by putting `table2 = {}` before the function is executed, but it continues to display the error message.

How do I assign the values of a returned hash to a variable, so that I can print them using their `keys`?

Comment: Why are you only looking at the first line of the file?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, I'm using a for loop to look at all the lines of the file.

Comment: You return in the first iteration no matter what, before you get a chance to look at the second line.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What's going on is that you're returning right after the first line of the file doesn't match the id you're looking for. You have to do this:

```
def query(id):
    for line in file:
        table = {}
        (table["ID"],table["name"],table["city"]) = line.split(";")
        if id == int(table["ID"]):
             file.close()
             return table
    # ID not found; close file and return empty dict
    file.close()
    return {}
```

Comment: Thank you all. I hadn't realized that I was closing the file as part of the loop, making the file unreadable after the first line(if I understood correctly). Thank you again, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
def query(id):
    for line in file:
        table = line.split(";")
        if id == int(table[0]):
             yield table
    
    

id = int(input("Enter the ID of the user: "))
for id_, name, city in query(id):
  print("ID: " + id_)
  print("Name: " + name)
  print("City: " + city)
file.close()
```

Using yield..

Answer (score 0):

```
def prepare_table_row(row):
    lst = [i.text for i in row if i != u'\n']
    return dict(rank = int(lst[0]),
                grade = str(lst[1]),
                channel=str(lst[2])),
                videos = float(lst[3].replace(",", " ")),
                subscribers = float(lst[4].replace(",", "")),
                views = float(lst[5].replace(",", "")))
```

Answer (score -1):

I followed approach as shown in code below to return a dictionary. Created a class and declared dictionary as global and created a function to add value corresponding to some keys in dictionary.

**Note have used Python 2.7 so some minor modification might be required for Python 3+

```
class a:
    global d
    d={}
    def get_config(self,x):
        if x=='GENESYS':
            d['host'] = 'host name'
            d['port'] = '15222'
        return d
```

Calling get_config method using class instance in a separate python file:

```
from constant import a
class b:
    a().get_config('GENESYS')
    print a().get_config('GENESYS').get('host')
    print a().get_config('GENESYS').get('port')
```